# OCMock mock protocol's static class method.

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

New in OCMock 3 is the ability to mock out [class methods](http://ocmock.org/reference/#mocking-class-methods).

Is it possible to mock class methods defined in a protocol? i.e

```
@protocol AViewControllerProtocol <NSObject>
+ (Type)typeForViewController;
@end
```

Inside my unit test class

```
- (void)testProtocolClassMethod {
    id mockedViewController = OCMProtocolMock(@protocol(AViewControllerProtocol));

    //This line compiles fine, but throws an exception at run time.
    OCMStub([mockedViewController typeForViewController]).andReturn(SomeType);
}
```

Exception throw

> NSInvalidArgumentException: cannot stub/expect/verify method 'typeForViewController' because no such method exists in the mocked class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it was an oversight in OCMock 3.1, but you can make the fix yourself, if you want.

```
// OCProtocolMockObject.m
- (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)aSelector
{
    struct objc_method_description methodDescription = protocol_getMethodDescription(mockedProtocol, aSelector, YES, YES);
    if(methodDescription.name == NULL) 
    {
        methodDescription = protocol_getMethodDescription(mockedProtocol, aSelector, NO, YES);
    }
    // Add this case for required class methods
    if (methodDescription.name == NULL)
    {
        methodDescription = protocol_getMethodDescription(mockedProtocol, aSelector, YES, NO);
    }
    // Add this case for optional class methods
    if (methodDescription.name == NULL)
    {
        methodDescription = protocol_getMethodDescription(mockedProtocol, aSelector, NO, NO);
    }
    if(methodDescription.name == NULL)
    {
        return nil;
    }
    return [NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:methodDescription.types];
}
```

I verified this fix with this test:

```
- (void)testProtocolClassMethod {
    id mockedViewController = OCMProtocolMock(@protocol(AViewControllerProtocol));

    // FIXED: This line compiles fine, but throws an exception at run time.
    OCMStub([mockedViewController typeForViewController]).andReturn(SomeType);

    Type type = [mockedViewController typeForViewController];

    XCTAssertEqual(type, SomeType, @"Not equal!");

    OCMVerify([mockedViewController typeForViewController]);
}
```

I'll put a request in on the project page for this.

Comment: I've not had time to review this answer yet, but it looks great thanks.

Well done.

Comment: Using OCMock 2.2.4 and having same issue.

Comment: I've just pushed a fix to master.